# Interpreting a question from topics in Banach space theory

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am (roughly) quoting from exercise 2.6 in "Topics in Banach Space Theory"

"Suppose $X$ is Banach with separable dual. If $\sum x_n^*$ is a series in $X^*$ such that every subseries converges weak-*, then $\sum x_n$ converges in norm."

How is $x_n^*$ supposed to be interpreted here? Does it mean any biothorgonal functionals?

Doesn't this imply that if $\sum x_n^*$ converges weak-*, then $\sum  x_n$ converges in norm?

Comment: The question does not make sense. Are you sure you have copied it properly?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, it appears to be a typo in the text

Comment: Who is the author of this book?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Albaic and Kalton. Sorry about the late reply!

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to just be a typo, and it should say $\sum x_n^*$ at the end instead of $\sum x_n$.  That is, $(x_n^*)$ is just an arbitrary sequence in $X^*$, and the ${}^*$ has no special meaning.

Comment: Thank you! Does this imply that a series that converges weak-* converges in norm (this seems wrong, even tacking on $X$ is separable and reflexive)? Or is it now the case that if $\sum x_n$ converges weak-* then every subseries does?

Comment: The latter: a subseries of a convergent series need not converge.  For instance, in a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)$, $\sum_n (e_n-e_{n-1})$ converges weakly (the partial sums telescope and the "end" of the telescope is converging weakly to $0$), but if you take a subseries you will lose the cancellation and it typically won't converge weakly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: The question was not how to solve the problem, but what the problem means.  So, the question has been answered.